# How to remove dash between spaces using regex?

Tags: php, regex

**Input:** tomato – 500-600 g

**Output:** tomato 500-600 g

Comment: That really simple job. What did you try? What doesn't work?

Comment: `str_replace(" – ", " ", "tomato – 500-600 g")`

Comment: try this **preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', 'tomato – 500-600 g')**;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/\s\–\s/
```

will find space dash space. Use that to replace it with a single space.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to implement through regex is:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', 'tomato – 500-600 g');
```

and if you don't want to use regex method. The simple method is:

```
str_replace(" – ", " ", "tomato – 500-600 g")
```